# SQL Server Reporting Services Anonymous Authentication issues

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

SQL Server 2005 and earlier allows users to seamless integratiom of Anonymous Authentication with their apps.

However, this is not supported in SSRS and 2008 (R2).

After extensive browsing, I found this article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jameswu/archive/2008/07/15/anonymous-access-in-sql-rs-2008.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage

After configuring three of the config files alluded to in the article, and compiling the c class into dll, I am running into the following errors when attempting to invoke SSRS reports using php.

```
The Authentication Extension threw an unexpected exception or returned a value that is not valid: . (rsAuthenticationExtensionError) Get Online Help
    For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors
```

I have run out of ideas and would grealy appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks a lot in advance.

The SSRS reporting server and SQL Server database reside on server and the php that calls these reports reside on another server.

I have tried some of the suggestions on this site but none has worked for me so far.

Comment: This class is a custom security library that is overriding the Authorization() and Authentication() pieces. Are you able to compile the library and make sure it is using the proper ReportingServices interface for 2008?

Comment: @lrb, what exactly do you mean by proper ReportingServices interface?

Comment: The ReportingServices2005.asmx web service's interface is what I was referring to.

Comment: @lrb, I successfully compiled the library into AnonymousSecurity.dll as described in the article.

I don't see any reference to ReportingServices2005.asmx or how it is used in conjunction with the compile library.

I just need to be convinced that though the reports are being called from php on another server, that no additional configuration is needed on that calling server.

Comment: SSRS can be configured to have a custom assembly provide  authorization and authentication for each request. That is what that library is doing and I assume it is giving read only access to each request regardless of credentials. I don't know how reports are deployed if there is no login provided. Anyway, it seems that your custom security library is returning a value that is not valid. At this point, I would look into the ssrs logs and enable remote errors in the web config so you can find the offending line(s) and make the necessary changes.

Comment: @lrb, I am not sure if indeed this made a difference but I recompiled the library again, this time, using VSS 2008 and it seems to have solved the riddle.

So, all is well now. Thanks for your time.